# Sort tags array by popularity

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I'm loading an array of tags and would like to sort them by popularity where the most popular word should be listed first and so on.
How to do that?

PHP:

```
function addTags($jsonArray)
{
    $output = array();
    foreach($jsonArray['response']['posts'] as $post)
    {
        foreach($post['tags'] as $tag)
        {
                $output[] = $tag;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

JSON tag example:

```
["mostpopular","single","mostpopular","foo","foo","mostpopular","bar"]
```

Comment: what tells which tag is "most popular"?  if it's tagged with "mostpopular"?

Comment: What would you want your array to look like afterwards? `["mostpopular", "foo", "bar", "single"]`? As in, organised by which is the most common tag?

Comment: `As in, organised by which is the most common tag?` Yes.

Comment: @sircapsalot That's just an example, "mostpopular" is the most popular tag in that array.

Comment: I assume this is a JSON API you are pulling this data from.. In this case, you should have your API able to do that sorting *for* you.  Example: http://example.com/api/posts?sortby=mostpopular

Comment: What research have you done / what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This it helps

```
$jsonArray = array ("mostpopular","single","mostpopular","foo","foo","mostpopular","bar");

$jsonresult = array_count_values($jsonArray);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($jsonresult);echo '</pre>';
//Array (  [mostpopular] => 3 [single] => 1    [foo] => 2    [bar] => 1)    
$jsonsort = arsort($jsonresult);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($jsonresult);echo '</pre>';
// Array ([mostpopular] => 3 [foo] => 2 [single] => 1        [bar] => 1)
```

Comment: If I `print_r($jsonsort);` it shows "1" instead of the arsorted Array. Do I miss something?

Comment: edited my answer print_r($jsonresult); instead  print_r($jsonsort);